# Fetching Tumblr posts using tag name is ot working

Tags: java, tags, tumblr, jumblr

Hi i tried java code to fetch the Tumblr posts using tag name.

```
List<Post> posts = client.tagged(tagName, options);
```

Using this I am able to fetch the posts if i am passing some regular tags but if i pass my own tag "#manindar" (I have posted using this tag name in a blog & on my timeline as well) i am not able to get those posts. But using blogname i am able to fetch the same post. But i want to get from the tagname.

You can see by this as well

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=manindar&api_key=****
```

You can see my posts [here](https://www.tumblr.com/blog/gmani412)

Comment: The provided code seems to work - what are you getting back @Manindar?

Comment: Yes now it is working now. But actually there is a restriction from tumblr that if we add any new hashtag then it will give some restriction on that new hashtag, after certain days only the hashtag will be actively working. But they did not mentioned that number of days anywhere. It depends on the hashtag frequency i guess.